# Microsoft Access - Search Query

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2013

I have two strings:

```
1. #ck#
2. #c44#
```

these are located in a string like

> "#CK# Site B: Umbau der IDU vom in Delta-Cabinets und Auflage der STM-1 auf ODF"

I am unable to use a function that is similar to isnumber(search) in Excel.
I want to find #ck# or #c44# in a string and then use iif for further naming it to something more meaningful.

Comment: Have you tried the `Replace()` function? Or `InStr()` to see if a string is contained in another string.

Comment: I have tried inst() but was unable to get what was actually required.

Answer (score 0):

I have used two ways to find your strings. 
First, if I place your string in Cell(1,1) (I also added the #c44# to that string)
in Cell(1,2) I entered formula:

```
=FIND("#c44#",A1,1)
```

Note that the CASE must match or it will not find the string!

The second method is the following Function

```
Option Explicit

Function Find_Pound()
Dim strString   As String
Dim strFind1    As String
Dim i           As Integer

'"#CK# Site B: Umbau der IDU vom in Delta-Cabinets und Auflage der #c44# STM-1 auf ODF"
    strString = Sheet1.Cells(1, 1)      
    strFind1 = "#CK#"
    i = InStr(1, strString, strFind1)
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Found: '" & strFind1 & "' at position: " & i
    End If

    strFind1 = "#c44#"
    i = InStr(1, strString, strFind1)
    If i > 0 Then
        MsgBox "Found: '" & strFind1 & "' at position: " & i
    End If

End Function
```